# ERROR: Class does not expose a management interface

Tags: java, jboss, tomcat7, jboss6.x

I am installing our ERP Solution developed in Java onto my IBM System X3750 M4 Server. I have downloaded and installed the JRE from IBM; the package name is: `ibm-java-x86_64-jre-7.0-5.0.x86_64`.

My Application Server is JBoss 6.0 and Client Server is Apache Tomcat 7.0.14 and Database is MYSQL 5.1.69.

While starting the JBoss Server I am getting an error as given in the bottom of my Question.

Any idea on how can it be resolved?

```
18:03:29,265 INFO  [AbstractServer] Starting: JBossAS [6.0.0.Final "Neo"]
18:03:30,482 ERROR [STDERR] javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: Class does not expose a management interface: java.lang.Object
18:03:30,483 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.metadata.MBeanCapability.of(MBeanCapability.java:101)
18:03:30,483 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.metadata.MBeanCapability.of(MBeanCapability.java:99)
18:03:30,483 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.registerMBean(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:200)
18:03:30,483 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
18:03:30,483 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:76)
18:03:30,484 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
18:03:30,484 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
18:03:30,484 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
18:03:30,484 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
18:03:30,484 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:138)
18:03:30,484 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:90)
18:03:30,485 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:140)
18:03:30,485 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:90)
18:03:30,485 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271)
18:03:30,485 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670)
18:03:30,485 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl$3.run(MBeanServerImpl.java:1443)
18:03:30,485 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:330)
18:03:30,486 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:1438)
18:03:30,486 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:378)
18:03:30,486 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.registerPlatformBeans(ManagementFactory.java:786)
18:03:30,486 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.access$100(ManagementFactory.java:42)
18:03:30,486 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory$1.run(ManagementFactory.java:373)
18:03:30,486 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:274)
18:03:30,487 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(ManagementFactory.java:371)
18:03:30,487 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
18:03:30,487 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:76)
18:03:30,487 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
18:03:30,487 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
18:03:30,487 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.system.server.jmx.JMXKernel.start(JMXKernel.java:182)
18:03:30,488 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
18:03:30,488 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:76)
18:03:30,488 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
18:03:30,488 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
18:03:30,488 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60)
18:03:30,488 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168)
18:03:30,489 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
18:03:30,489 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:257)
18:03:30,489 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
18:03:30,489 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:125)
18:03:30,489 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:72)
18:03:30,490 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:202)
18:03:30,490 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
18:03:30,490 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
18:03:30,490 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
18:03:30,490 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
18:03:30,490 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
18:03:30,491 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379)
18:03:30,491 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044)
18:03:30,491 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083)
18:03:30,491 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322)
18:03:30,491 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246)
18:03:30,491 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139)
18:03:30,492 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:894)
18:03:30,492 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:641)
18:03:30,492 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBean(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:319)
18:03:30,492 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBeans(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:297)
18:03:30,492 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deploy(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:130)
18:03:30,493 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.BasicKernelDeployer.deploy(BasicKernelDeployer.java:76)
18:03:30,493 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.mc.deployer.TempBasicXMLDeployer.deploy(TempBasicXMLDeployer.java:92)
18:03:30,493 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.mc.deployer.TempBasicXMLDeployer.deploy(TempBasicXMLDeployer.java:193)
18:03:30,493 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.mc.server.AbstractMCServerBase.bootstrapMcAndDescriptors(AbstractMCServerBase.java:310)
18:03:30,493 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.mc.server.AbstractMCServerBase.doStart(AbstractMCServerBase.java:257)
18:03:30,493 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.as.server.AbstractJBossASServerBase.doStart(AbstractJBossASServerBase.java:381)
18:03:30,494 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:413)
18:03:30,494 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:781)
```

Comment: I would talk to your developers who developed it.

Comment: Have you verified that you follow the naming convention for the management interface? If you call it the wrong thing you could see this exception. There is a similar problem in this [link](https://community.jboss.org/thread/51954?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually missing some libraries in jboss that caused the error. Because it was actually happened when I tried to make jboss light by removing unused jars. Any way restoring the jboss libraries took away this error.