# javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: Class does not expose a management interface: java.lang.Object

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss5.x, ejb-2.x, jboss-messaging

We are migrating from JBoss-4.0.4-GA to JBoss-5.1.0-GA. When I start JBoss I'm getting following error:

```
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying: jboss.messaging:service=Queue,name=MyQueueTest
Caused by: javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: Class does not expose a management interface: java.lang.Object
```

I got one link [ERROR: Class does not expose a management interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736533/error-class-does-not-expose-a-management-interface) which says to add some libraries but it does not specify where to add which library. Following is the mbean under destination-service.xml

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService" name="jboss.messaging:service=Queue,name=MyQueueTest">
    <depends optional-attribute-name="ServerPeer">jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer</depends>
    <depends>jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice</depends>
    <attribute name="MessageCounterHistoryDayLimit">-1</attribute>
    <attribute name="SecurityConf">
        <security>
            <role name="guest" read="true" write="true"/>
            <role name="publisher" read="true" write="true" create="false"/>
            <role name="noacc" read="false" write="false" create="false"/>
        </security>
    </attribute>
</mbean>
```

Comment: What profile are you using in JBoss 5.x?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved. I checked the dummy examples for defining the queue in JBoss-5.1.0-GA. I was missing attribute **xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Queue-xmbean.xml"**. After this change, it becomes as below

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService"
 name="jboss.messaging:service=Queue,name=MyQueueTest"
 xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Queue-xmbean.xml">
<depends optional-attribute-name="ServerPeer">jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer</depends>
<depends>jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice</depends>
<attribute name="MessageCounterHistoryDayLimit">-1</attribute>
<attribute name="SecurityConf">
  <security>
    <role name="guest" read="true" write="true"/>
    <role name="publisher" read="true" write="true" create="false"/>
    <role name="noacc" read="false" write="false" create="false"/>
  </security>
</attribute>
```